# Does c9.io suspend like Heroku?

Tags: ide, cloud9-ide

I'm developing a small "pet-project" using c9.io service. 
Does c9.io suspend like heroku? 
Do I need to start server manually if it is? 
I can't find this kind of information in official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud9 does stop processes after certain amounts of time depending on what plan you're on. See [official documentation](https://docs.c9.io/docs/inactive-workspaces) for up to date information.